# Asp.Net Core 2.2 UseUrls is ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, kestrel

I have the following code in my Asp.Net Core 2.2

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var urls = new string[] { "https://localhost:3045" };
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args, urls).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args, string[] bindingUrls) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
            .ConfigureKestrel(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddServerHeader = false;
            })
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseUrls(bindingUrls)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

However when I debug the site is launched on `https://localhost:44326/` why is used in launchSettings.json
Why is that happening?

Comment: Are you launching IIS express or executable directly? It's a combobox near run button in Visual Studio.

Comment: launcing using IIS Express.

Comment: isn't ```https://localhost:44326/``` set in project properties? if you build your project in release instead of debug, does it work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.UseUrls(bindingUrls)` will configure Kestrel url.

dotnet core always sits in Kestrel behind `IIS`/`IIS Express` as a proxy. The url you get is the configuration for your `IIS Express`.

This url can be changed in your project settings or `launchSettings.json`

If you would like to just run on Kestrel user the cli command `dotnet run` or `dotnet watch run`

Comment: You can either run IIS Express or run project directly - it's a UI option in visual studio, cli commands are not necessary.